# Failure in loading native library db2jcct2

Tags: spring-boot, db2, spring-data

I have a spring boot application that uses Cassandra and DB2 databases. 
I added the needed configuration to the application.yml file.

Note: my Cassandra and DB2 databases are remote(not local).

Here is what I have in the yaml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:db2://myRemoteHost:portNumber/MyDBName
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

  data:
    cassandra:
      cluster-name: cluster name
      keyspace-name: keyspace name
      port: myPortNumber
      contact-points: host1.com
      username: username
      password: password
```

Here is the dependency I'm using in my application:

```
compile group: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc', name: 'db2jcc', version: 'db2jcc4'
```

When I run the application I got the error below:

```
    Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][4.25.13] 
Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
no db2jcct2 in java.library.path:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that your application tries to use type 2 connection. You should make it use type 4 one.

[Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, UnsatisfiedLinkError: ERRORCODE=-4472](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978)

Comment: Yeah, the application was using type 2 connection instead of type 4. That was because of some dependencies that were used in build.gradle file. For my case I just deleted those dependencies because I don't need them. In some other cases, we can just exclude the connection dependencies instead of deleting the whole dependency.